# What is the best IDE for web development?

Tags: web-development, html, php, ide, css

What is the best IDE (interactive development environment) for web development and design?

Programing languages: HTML, PHP, CSS, JavaScript.

Is there any programing language that worth learning or beginners?

Comment: Everyone is looking for "the best" software. It's a very subjective term. What does "the best" mean for you? Is price relevant? If "the best" costs 25.000 US$, is it good for you? If "the best" needs 64 GB RAM, can you run it? If "the best" only works on Linux, will you install Linux then? As you can see, the term "the best" has limitations. What are your limitations?

Comment: "Is there any programing language that worth learning or beginners?" - that question is off-topic here. Any programming language is worth learning. Depends on your interest and the field you want to work in. Obviously you already have chosen web development as your flavour. Start with HTML, since that will be the basis for including JavaScript and CSS. Also, PHP will need HTML knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend you Visual Studio Code (VS Code). It is used by most of the developers nowadays, especially by those who build web, native or hybrid applications. It offers great documentation and its extensions (plugins) are just awesome. Its IntelliSense system, which is an AI service, provides you with a variety of code editing features. For example, code completion, parameter info, quick info, and member lists. Furthermore, it comes with great extensions for supporting Docker, MySQL or PostgreSQL, Angular, React and of course Python. You can debug directly your code or use LiveServer to test your HTML file directly with Chrome. Also, it has a great integrated terminal, either for your terminal, bash or command prompt.

If you are on Windows, it also has an extension for the Windows Subsystem for Windows (WSL). Last but not least, it has great support for GitHub too, as Microsoft owns both VS Code & Github. You can initialize a new repository, track any changes in your files and finally commit them to your repo.

I hope that helps! Please let me know if there is anything else I can help you with.